# Build LibrSvg as static library for visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I need to use librSvg library in a project for svg conversion to other formats (for example pdf). This is the only library that I manage to find that suits my needs (to convert a majority of embedded fonts from svg).

My problem is that I do not know how to proceed because librSvg has a huge amount of dependencies like:

- libcairo-2.dll
- libcroco-0.6-3.dll
- libffi-6.dll
- libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll
- libgio-2.0-0.dll
- libglib-2.0-0.dll
- libgmodule-2.0-0.dll
- libgobject-2.0-0.dll
- libiconv-2.dll
- libintl-8.dll
- libpango-1.0-0.dll
- libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll
- libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll
- libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll
- libpixman-1-0.dll
- libpng16-16.dll
- librsvg-2-2.dll
- libxml2-2.dll
- zlib1.dll

I manage to find the binary files [librSvg binaries](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ed03dfd0f92065a39d19038cfbc35e4d20180612062324/c7ed2a) and the sources from the official git repository [librSvg repository](https://github.com/GNOME/librsvg).

Can somebody please guide me about how can I make a static library (.lib) from this files that can I use as a standalone entity in my project?

Comment: Do you want to have all *.dll files as one (static) *.lib? A little sidenote: It is licenced under GPL, you should check if static linking is allowed for your purpose.

Comment: Yes this is what I attend to do. And from my experience either static or dynamic linking is fine as long that is not for commercial purpose.

Comment: Basically, you need to download the sources and build the static libs on your own. After that, you can build one executable with static linking (just "include" the static libs in Visual Studio, not the dlls, that should do it). That should make your executable (runtime) independent from the mentioned libraries

Comment: Hmm that makes sense. So I need to find the source code of all the 19 libraries and compile them individually in order to make the static library. I hope to find them all. Thanks.